# Expectation of a local martingale and uniform integrability

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $N_t$ be a local martingale and $\tau_n$ be the localizing sequence. As per the book I am following then we have the following
[image]

I dont understand how uniform integrability will make the expectation constant. Can anyone please explain this part?

Comment: Is $N$ non-negative (with $N_0=1$)?  Or at least bounded below?  Else, Fatou is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that in this book local martingales are normalised so that $\mathbb{E}[N_0] = 1$ (otherwise $N_t$ can clearly be a martingale with a different expectation).

In this case,
$$\mathbb{E}[N_{t \wedge \tau_n}] = \mathbb{E}[N_{0 \wedge \tau_n}] = \mathbb{E}[N_0] = 1$$
for each $n$. $N_{t \wedge \tau_n} \to N_t$ pointwise a.e. as $n \to \infty$. Uniform integrability and pointwise a.e. convergence imply convergence of the integrals so that $$\mathbb{E}[N_t] = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[N_{t \wedge \tau_n}] = 1.$$

Comment: Hi even though the statement U.I + CV in probability  <=> L^1 CV is largely known or precisely U.I + a.s. CV => L^1 CV, this is far from being obvious IMO so here is a link (theorem 1 page 4) to the claim : https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2018/lecture-notes/MIT6_436JF18_lec19.pdf

Comment: @TheBridge Fair enough, my assumption was that by the time one has encountered local martingales, any reasonably constructed course would have mentioned this but it is useful to have a reference here just in case; so thank you!

Comment: Well the forum is opened worldwide so I think it's better not assume too much prior knowledge (as there are many ways math are teached) or at least to be as explicit as possible when a result is used in an answer. Anyway your answer was clear and my comment was a matter of personnal taste.